# Ringtone setting in Lumia 525

Tags: ringtone

In Lumia 525 I am unable to set MP3 ringtone. I connected my cell with my laptop by it did not shown any ringtone+sound folder. It shows only ringtone folder which is created in my music library.

Answer (score 0):

### From Nokia's [faqs](http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA140238)

On the start screen, **swipe left, tap Settings > ringtones+sounds**, select the type of ringtone or alert you want to change, and select the sound.

If you have an mp3 file of a song on your PC, you can make it your ringtone.

1. Connect your phone to your PC, and use the file manager of your PC
   to move the song you want to use as a ringtone to the ringtone
   folder in your phone.
2. To set the song as your ringtone, in the ringtones+sounds view, tap
   Ringtone, and under Custom, tap the song.
3. You can use a song as your ringtone if it's not protected with
   digital rights management (DRM), and it’s smaller than 30 MB.

> Your PC must have Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8.

Also you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXKQIlmNSh8).